# Customize WordPress API Query

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm developing an app and retrieving a list of posts via WP's Api, but I needed a parameter to retrieve only posts that have video, which is a custom field called meta_video

Example: https://meusite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1 retrieves all posts from category 1

Example 2: https://meusite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?meta_video=true to pass a parameter by the URL and retrieve all posts that have a video iframe.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution might be creating a new API endpoint ( https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ )

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_rest_post_with_videos_endpoint' );
function my_rest_post_with_videos_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'post/with-videos', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'my_post_with_videos',
    ) );
}
```

And in this endpoint just return a meta query where you get all the posts with that meta: example query

```
function my_post_with_videos( $request = null ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'meta_query' = array(
            array(
             'key'     => 'meta_video',
             'compare' => 'EXISTS',
           ),
    );

    $response =  new WP_Query( $args );

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 200 );
}
```

Please keep in mind this is a very basic example with no validations or error checks.

Comment: Thanks I could return the posts with videos, now the question would be, how to do other filters? Example, start and end date, authors, retrieve metadata and delete api query if you have a link to help me I appreciate it.

Comment: I already gave it - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/. For every filter just add another route with a corresponding callback function. Example :   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_rest_post_with_videos_endpoint' );
function my_rest_post_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'post/with-videos', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'my_post_with_videos',
    ) ), register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'post/start-date', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'my_post_start_date',
    ) );
}